# Browser cookies inspector

Tags: cookies

In developer tools in FF under Storage, and in Chrome under Application->storage, I can see eg. cookies that is saved on a particular domain. But I must visit the domain to see all the data the cookies have stored.
I'd like to select which cookie to inspect without visiting each indivdual site!
All I can do is to see which sites have stored data but i can't see which data it holds.

Anyone knows how to see that?

Comment: It was possible in older versions of Firefox - in the place where you see which sites have stored data, you could expand each individual site and view the cookies it has stored. It was very useful, but since some time they have removed that feature...

Comment: [Cookie Quick Manager – Get this Extension for  Firefox (en-GB)](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/cookie-quick-manager/)

Comment: [View, Edit, And Delete Cookies With Chrome DevTools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/storage/cookies)